# Automapper running extremely slow on mapping 1400 records

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using AUtomapper which I am very impressed with however, I have a complex object with many nested collections. I'm using Telerik OpenAccess and it returns the 1400 records fast but when I pass it to Automapper and it slows to a ridiculous crawl. Here is my code for reference:

```
        List<DAL.Event> query = httpContext.Events.Where(e => e.Inactive != true && e.Event_Locations != null).ToList();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Event, EventDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Event_Association, EventAssociationDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Event_ExecutingUnit, EventExecutingUnitDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Event_Funding, EventFundingDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Event_Location, EventLocationDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Event_Objective, EventObjectiveDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Event_OSR, EventOSRDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Event_PaxBreakDown, EventPAXBreakDownDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Event_RegionalConsideration, EventRegionalConsiderationDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Event_ReviewStatus, EventReviewStatusDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Event_SPCalendarClone, EventSPCalendarClonesDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Event_Task, EventTasksDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DAL.Event_TSO, EventTSOsDTO>();
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        Mapper.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;

        IList<EventDTO> result = Mapper.Map<List<DAL.Event>, List<EventDTO>>(query);
        return result;
```

HELP!

Comment: Which version of AutoMapper are you using?

Comment: What is that ridiculous value?

Comment: You might want to use a profiler (ie. dotTrace) to analyze which part of code is running slow.

Comment: Just one little thing - if you're calling CreateMap every time, that's going to be waaaaaay slower.

Comment: I know this is extremely old, but the fact that you were creating the mapping, especially of so many objects, in between each query and output, means you likely never fully understood how to use AutoMapper in the first place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There was a team at my previous job who were also using Automapper but in the end they removed it because of the performance impact.

I think in this specific scenario it's best to write the mapping code yourself, or start replacing them one by one. Maybe one mapping is causing the bad performance?

Comment: Automapper is a nifty utility but it is orders of magnitude slower than direct mapping. On one recent project, it seemed to be more than 1,000 times slower than doing a direct mapping. I have never looked at the automapper code but suspect that its heavy use of reflection is the primary culprit for the performance issues. For data migration type applications, direct mapping is probably the best approach.

Comment: I may be beating the horse here, but her is my experience. My team also stopped using AutoMapper, because it had a difficult time mapping Bi-Directional mappings and parent / child relationships (in Entity Framework and Dynamic Proxies generated because of Lazy Loading). We also experienced very slow response times and found it was our main bottle-neck when we ran a profiler. We did look at using other mappers, but in the end it has tunred out to either use direct entities or handle the mappings directly to our DTOs.

Answer (score 14):

I benchmarked automapper.  A single core of a 2.0GHz Xeon is able to handle 85,000 maps per second, on a small object (3 properties).  It was 60 times slower than manually copying the properties.  If you'd like, I can benchmark other values for you.

Comment: so do you prefer to write a custom mapping one by one or or use a tool!?

Comment: @Ehsan: it depends, which is why I hide my mappings behind an interface.  My IoC container will fill in AutoMapper most of the time, but for time-critical ones I'll write a manu-map and configure that instance to be used.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think tools like this are designed for mapping so many records. I think AutoMapper is designed for mapping a View Model and it is not normal to display 1400 records on the screen.

Comment: I am using Telerik Rad grid which claims it can handle an obnoxious amount of data

Comment: Single viewmodel or (Paged/Limited) list. Mapping 1400 records shouldn't really be happening...

Comment: With the Telerik grid I think you can get it to load data on demand. So If you have paging with 50 records it will only load 50 and when you go to the next page it loads the next 50. Loading all up front doesn't really scale.

Answer (score 8):

For those coming to this later, AutoMapper 5.x release made significant performance improvements, where mapping speed is only slightly slower than hand mapping (1M items):

- Native: 0.19s
- AutoMapper: 0.49s
- AutoMapper 4.2.1: 29s