# Is there a shortcut to convert a model to a view model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to c# and .NET. I am learning ASP.NET MVC 5. One thing that I am finding myself spending extra time doing in converting a model to a viewmodel.

Here is my model

```
public class Overview
{

    public string chain_name { get; set; }
    public int store_id { get; set; }
    public int total_attempts { get; set; }
    public int total_unique_number_called { get; set;  }
    public int total_callable { get; set; }
    public int total_completed_interviews { get; set; }

}
```

and here is my view model

```
public class OverviewViewModel
{

    public string chain_name { get; set; }
    public int store_id { get; set; }
    public int total_attempts { get; set; }
    public int total_unique_number_called { get; set; }
    public int total_callable { get; set; }
    public int total_completed_interviews { get; set; }
    public decimal? unique_number_per_complete { get; set; }

    public OverviewViewModel()
    {
        unique_number_per_complete = 0;
    }

}
```

as you can see both Model and ViewModel are identical except for over variable which is a calculation.

To populate my view model I do the following

```
var records = conn.Database.SqlQuery<Overview>(query).ToList();

var overView = new List<OverviewViewModel>();

foreach(var record in records){

    var newRecord = new OverviewViewModel();

    newRecord.store_id = record.store_id;

    newRecord.chain_name = record.chain_name;

    newRecord.total_attempts = record.total_attempts;

    newRecord.total_callable = record.total_callable;

    newRecord.total_completed_interviews = record.total_completed_interviews;

    if (record.total_completed_interviews > 0) {
        newRecord.total_unique_number_called = record.total_unique_number_called / record.total_completed_interviews;
    }

    overView.Add(newRecord);
}
```

The two issues that I am seeing with my approach is that

1. I have to do lots of extra coding especially of the view model is large or f I have multiple variables that I need to calculate.
2. I feel I am looping 1 extra time to convert my model to view mode.

Is there an easier way to do this in c#?

Is there a better approach with this procedure for a large application? My goal is to learn the better way to utilize my code time to the fullest.

Comment: AutoMapper can help with the trivially mapping.

Comment: Be aware, Automapper is very slow, if you have large amountt of data tp process, think about own custom mapper  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131720/automapper-running-extremely-slow-on-mapping-1400-records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should use Automapper, install package view Nuget. Automapper is very configurable as well.

http://automapper.org/

First, create this class:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        //Example here, creates "two way" for Overview & OverviewViewModel mapping
        Mapper.CreateMap<Overview, OverviewViewModel>(); //<source, destination>
        Mapper.CreateMap<OverviewViewModel, Overview>(); //<source, destination>
        //..more mapping for other Models and ViewModels.
    }
}
```

In Global.asax.ApplicationStart() add this line:

```
AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings()
```

Now your foreach example in your comments is nice and simple:

```
foreach (var record in records)
{
    var newRecordOverviewViewModel = Mapper.Map<OverviewViewModel>(record); //<destination>(source)
    overView.Add(newRecordOverviewViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian. I just installed AutoMapper in my project. I am trying to use to by converting my Overview object to OverviewViewModel object. If this is truly what I need I will accept your answer. I am not sure if you have a short code that I should follow to convert the two object, but if you do that will help me a bunch. Thank you :)

Comment: Do you mind helping me with the syntax? This is what I have done, but I am getting currly read lines inder the 2 objects I am trying to map `foreach(var record in records){

 OverviewViewModel newRecord = new OverviewViewModel();

 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<record, newRecord>());

 var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
 var final = mapper.Map<newRecord>(record);

 overView.Add(final);

}`

Comment: Working on the syntax now, I can tell you that you DO NOT create a MapperConfiguration in the foreach loop  like you are doing, you just do that one time in your Global.asax. Will update answer for you.

Comment: @MikeA checkout my answer update with code, let me know if you have any questions, Automapper rocks and is exactly for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. One thing I should mention here that I got a warning when I used this approach that states `AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap... is obsolete: Dynamically creating maps will be removed in version 5.0. Use a Mapper Configuration instance and store statically as needed, or mapper.Initilize. Use CreateMapper to create a mapper instance`.

Comment: Hi @MikeA yes, I did not know Automapper is moving away from a static implementation of their library, checkout this article explaining how to change to the nonstatic setup: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/

Answer (score 5):

I agree that you should look into automapper, but another way would be to create a constructor on your OverviewViewModel model that takes and Overview object and populates all the properties. Something like

```
public class OverviewViewModel {

    public string chain_name { get; set; }
    public int store_id { get; set; }
    public int total_attempts { get; set; }
    public int total_unique_number_called { get; set; }
    public int total_callable { get; set; }
    public int total_completed_interviews { get; set; }
    public decimal? unique_number_per_complete { get; set; }

    public OverviewViewModel()
    {
        unique_number_per_complete = 0;
    }
public OverviewViewModel(Overview record)
    {
        store_id = record.store_id;

    chain_name = record.chain_name;

    total_attempts = record.total_attempts;

    total_callable = record.total_callable;
    //etc
    }
}
```

Then your code would look like

```
var overView = new List<OverviewViewModel>();

foreach(var record in records){
    overView.Add(new OverViewViewModel(record));
}
```

Comment: +1 Very good point! I will defiantly take that into consideration. But first I like to get the automapper to work as it seems to be the best approach

Comment: I also would think using auto mapper inside that constructor will be great to shorten my code instead of having to list each variable which can get long.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use Linq and extension methods as below

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using App.Data.Entities;
using App.Business.Models;

namespace App.Business
{
    public static partial class OverviewAdapter
    {
        public static OverviewViewModel ToOverviewViewModel(this Overview overview)
        {
            return new OverviewViewModel
            {
                chain_name                  =   overview.chain_name,
                store_id                    =   overview.store_id,
                total_attempts              =   overview.total_attempts,
                total_unique_number_called  =   overview.total_unique_number_called,
                total_callable              =   overview.total_callable,
                total_completed_interviews  =   overview.total_completed_interviews,
                unique_number_per_complete  =   0
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<OverviewViewModel> ToOverviewModelList(this IEnumerable<OverviewViewModel> overviewList)
        {
            return (overviewList != null) ? overviewList.Select(a => a.ToOverviewViewModel()) : new List<OverviewViewModel>();
        }

        // Reverse - ToOverview / ToOverviewList if needed...
   }
}
```

Now, anytime your Business class is in scope, you have a ***discoverable*** method on the class and the list of class which can be added inline.

```
var records = conn.Database.SqlQuery<Overview>(query).ToOverviewModelList().ToList();
```

This more functional approach is intuitive, streamlined, and you have immediate feedback if an adapter has not yet been written.

It is a personal preference whether to return an IEnumerable or List from the list version. The broader IEnumerable is the more conventional solution, but I tend to be going from List<> to List<> all of the time and dropping down into IEnumerable seems superfluous.